# require name instead of file path

Tags: node.js

I am looking at some code on github.

https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose/blob/master/config/routes.js

On line 7 it says.

```
var home = require('home');
```

home.js is in another folder. I am wondering how this works, and how I can do this in my own code.

on

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

it explains how to create a self-contained directory, but I can only find the package.json in the root folder. So how does this work? 
It seems like a more clean way than having direct file references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to refer to folders on the filesystem as packages in node, `npm link` for example, will pretend a folder is a module using symlinks.

The package you linked to is cheating a bit though, and I'd argue it's not clean at all when put like that. It's actually setting the `NODE_PATH` to include all controllers when the service is ran: https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose/blob/master/package.json#L13

So all controllers files like `home.js` are autmatically available. The `.js` is always optional anyway.

Comment: Ahh the path of course. yeah, agreed using NODE_PATH is not a nice way.  Thanks a lot!